# SQL, Check if Rows are in another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have two tables, `Stock` and `Warehouse`.

I need to get the Items which are available in all Warehouses.

Here an example:

```
Stock Table:

ItemID        WarehouseID        ItemAmount
-------------------------------------------
1043               1                20
1043               2                2
1043               3                16
1043               4                17
1044               1                32
1044               2                12
1044               4                7
1055               2                6
```

```
Warehouse Table:

WarehouseID       WarehouseName
-------------------------------
1                 Name1
2                 Name2
3                 Name3
4                 Name4
```

For the Example the result should be Item `1043` because its available in all Warehouses, unlike the other ones.

I didn't get to a solution, can anyone help me?

Comment: Re: _"I didn't get to a solution."_ Why not? SO is not a code writing service, so it would be only fair that you explain what *exactly* you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select itemid
from stock
group by itemid
having count(distinct warehouseid) = (select count(*) from warehouse);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e4273/1

If the stock table may also contain items with an amount = 0 you need to add a where clause:

```
select itemid
from stock
where itemamount > 0
group by itemid
having count(distinct warehouseid) = (select count(*) from warehouse);
```

Comment: Hmm, since we don't know what `UNIQUE` constraints there might be involved, perhaps it should be `COUNT(DISTINCT …)` instead of `COUNT(…)`?

Comment: @stakx: you are right. One should probably _also_ exclude items where the amount is zero

Answer (score 5):

You could also use this "double negative" query using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.ItemID
FROM StockTable s
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Warehouse w 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM StockTable s2 
                     WHERE w.WarehouseID = s2.WarehouseID
                     AND   s.ItemID = s2.ItemID)
)
```

<kbd>[**Demo fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/364ec/9/0)</kbd>

This approach looks more verbose but it has some benefits:

- you can change it easily if the rules are getting more complex
- you can remove the DISTINCT to see all rows
- you can add all columns since `GROUP BY` was not used
- it has no issues with null values

Answer (score 1):

`NOT EXISTS` combined with `EXCEPT`:

```
select distinct ItemID
from stock s1
where not exists (select warehouseid from warehouse
                  except 
                  select warehouseid from stock s2 where s2.ItemID = s1.ItemID);
```

You can even replace `select distinct ItemID` with `select *` to get all those items.

Answer (score 0):

I use this query:

```
SELECT 
    ItemID
FROM 
    stock
GROUP BY 
    ItemID
HAVING 
    SUM(DISTINCT warehouseid) = (SELECT SUM(WarehouseID) from warehouse)
```

That is more reliable than using `COUNT`, because in a rare situation of don't making a foreign key it should returns some invalid results.

Comment: You mean COUNT(DISTINCT warehouseid)?

Comment: @jarlh like a_horse_with_no_name answer ;).